# Joomla Login form error

Tags: joomla, authentication, module

I have installed joomla 3.0 version. When i type wrong password / username in login form, it comes out of joomla.

```
Error Message : 0 - Cannot open file for writing log
```

Its working in local machine and it gives message as :

Warning : Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.

Please help me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 5):

if this problem persists go into the logs folder and change the permissions of error.php  to 666

Mine has worked that way but had also changed other folders administrator/cache, logs, tmp to 777

Good times live PHP

Answer (score 1):

Failed login attempts are being saved in log `/logs/error.log`. Check permissions that this file and folder has writtable permissions.

You may change the path in System > Global Configuration > System > Path to Log Folder

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your folder permissions are set to **755** and file to **644**.

To check which files are folder are writable, go to:

```
Joomla backend >> Site (top menu) >> System Information >> Directory Permissions
```

Ensure that are are **writable**.

To mass change the permissions, you can use an extensions such as [Admin Tools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection/14087)

On a side note, you can also upgrade to Joomla 3.1 as it's now stable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is some time your hosting providers log folder and the joomla log folder is same.
You cannot change permission hosting providers "logs" folder.

Alternatively you create the log folder example "joomlalogs" in joomla installed root path and set the permission 777.
After that set the log folders path in configuration.php example "public $log_path = '/www/homepages/htdocs/joomlalogs';

Make it simple

Answer (score 0):

First find the exact absolute path to your **logs** folder by using this trick:

Create a PHP file in your website root,for example path.php

Place this snippet of code in the file and hit the save button

```
<?php
$path = getcwd();
echo "Your Absolute Path is: ";
echo $path;
?>
```

Navigate to yourdomain.com/path.php in your browser

From now on (using an ftp account or your file manger in your hosting service):

1. Navigate to your hosting root.
2. Open the **configuration.php** file
3. look for the line `public $log_path` change it's value to **"Absolute Path(you've just found)"/logs**
4. Save the **configuration.php** file
5. Now check the permission of the **logs** folder,it's inside the root, set the permission to **755**,and set the permissions of the inside files to **644**.
   And your done!

Answer (score -1):

In joomla backend try to unpublish the plugin with the name 'System - log' and try once.